# Socket isn't accepted in the thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

G'day guys. Recently, I decided to try my skills with TCP/IP, so at the moment I'm trying to write some kind of server/client chat, using sockets.

The thing I wanted to ask is interaction threads and sockets. Specifically, I'm interested in accept() function. I tried searching it, but didn't quite find similar situation.

So, the problem is - while I'm trying to accept socket outside of the thread, it works perfectly. Contrary, if I use it inside the thread, its' call is just ignored.

So, here's the method which calls accept function:

```
void ServerSocket::Accept( void )
{
    sockaddr_in saClientAddr;
    int nCliSize = sizeof( sockaddr_in );
    sClient = accept( sSocket, (sockaddr*)&saClientAddr, &nCliSize );

    if( sClient == INVALID_SOCKET )
    {
        GetError();
        return;
    }
}
```

So, using it in following manner:

```
CServerObj.Accept();
```

it works perfectly, and server waits for the input from the client and then resumes.
But, if it's used inside the thread:

```
unsigned __stdcall ServerThread( void* Param )
{
    while( true )
    {
        CServerObj.Accept();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and than begin the thread:

```
_beginthreadex( 0, 0, &ServerThread, 0, 0, NULL );
```

then accept() is ignored every time and program goes into the infinite loop telling about the error (GetError method).

So, I'm kinda confused with this situation. Is this because thread call is asynchronous and therefore it doesn't wait for client's response?

Anyway, I'd be grateful if someone could explain me what did I do wrong.

---

So, after some trial & effort, I figured out the reason behind this strange behavior. It seems like, `CServerObj`, which was declared as `static` called constructor twice, therefor rendering `bind` function useless. Figures, that was stupid error on my part.

But well, now I have another question - why was constructor called twice there?
Code in the header looked like this:

```
#ifndef __BLAH_H__
#define __BLAH_H__

class ServerSocket
{
    //some code
}
static ServerSocket CServerObj;

#endif // __BLAH_H__
```

I suppose it could be because variable was declared in the header file... but shouldn't `#ifndef` protect it against second declarations?

Comment: What sockets implementation are you using?

Comment: ..and what error is continually reported?  Also, where is the thread getting its CServerObj instance from?  Usually, such a thing is passed in as the 'Param', cast appropriately and then methods called on it.

Comment: WinSock, I guess, if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Well, error consists of gibberish symbols, but ultimately, its' cause is that sClient contains INVALID_SOCKET value.

Comment: CServerObj is a global variable, so it's just gets it from global namespace. I didn't use it as the way you told, because there's another thread for messages handling - it also requires CServerObj, but as Param there's SOCKET instance passed. Like this

`code
unsigned __stdcall MessageThread( void* Param )
{
 SOCKET sCliSock = (SOCKET) Param;
 while( true )
 {
  if( CServerObj.Recieve( sCliSock ) )
  {
   break;
  }
 }
 return 0;
}
`

Comment: You should at least use a different `sClient` handle per thread.

Comment: Well, yeah, there is one SOCKET handle for server thread, and separate SOCKET handles for each client thread.